# Does fileatime() "access" the file?

Tags: php, file

I was wondering whether or not fileatime counts as having accessed the file?

I'm assuming not as the function should really only need to access the filesystem metadata for the file rather than the file itself - is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. The underlying `stat()` call does not modify the file metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it has to be accessing the filesystem, because only the filesystem has the modtime, creationtime and accesstime saved.

Comment: Yes, but only the "metadata" part of the filesystem. It doesn't have to open/seek to the actual file contents. (Nor does it record that it was "accessed".)

Comment: Yes and it really depends on your mountoptions. If your filesystem is mounted with "noatime" then your filesystem does not record the accesstime. If your filesystem is mounted with noatime, then your current atime is your mtime. The so called Metadata are Nodes, INodes in case of ext3. Dunno how it's called on other filesystems like NTFS. Off Topic End :)